# Automatically cancelling Tradingview Paper trading orders

Tags: tradingview-api

I am forward testing  setup using Trading View Paper trading

One thing I would like to be able to automate is to automatically pull orders when a new high or low is made invalidating the setup

The logic will be based a certain price level

I was hoping using something similar to Alerts but instead of alerts, the approach through pull the orders

Anyone familiar  with a way to achieve this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To cancel all pending order you can use :

```
strategy.cancel_all()
```

if the order is already in trade, you can use

```
strategy.close_all()
```